# Search loop in json files

Tags: javascript, json

I have two json files : house and people. I'd like to find all people living in a house.
Here is my json files :

house :

```
{
    "HOUSES": {
        "1": {
            "NAME": "House1",
            "ID": 1
        },
        "2": {
            "NAME": "House2",
            "ID": 2
        },
        "3": {
            "NAME": "House3",
            "ID": 3
        }
    }
}
```

People :

```
{
    "PEOPLE": {
        "1": {
            "NAME": "People1",
            "HOUSE_ID": 1
        },
        "2": {
            "NAME": "People2",
            "HOUSE_ID": 2
        },
        "3": {
            "NAME": "People3",
            "HOUSE_ID": 2
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to list all people related to his house. Eg : list all people for House2. Result will be People2 and People3.

I tried to do two for loops :

```
//var houses and var peoples are the json files.
for(var i in houses){
    console.log(houses[i]);
    if(peoples.HOUSE_ID == houses[i].ID){
        for(var j in peoples){
            console.log(peoples[j].HOUSE_ID);
        }
    }
}
```

The loop doesn't want to enter in the if statement. What should I do?

Thanks.

EDIT :
Here the result of the both `console.log()` :

```
HOUSE_ID :  { name: 'House1',
  id: 1 }
People id { NAME: 'People1',
  HOUSE_ID: 1 }
People id { NAME: 'People2',
  HOUSE_ID: 2 }
People id { NAME: 'People3',
  HOUSE_ID: 2 }
HOUSE_ID :  { name: 'House2',
  id: 2 }
People id { NAME: 'People1',
  HOUSE_ID: 1 }
People id { NAME: 'People2',
  HOUSE_ID: 2 }
People id { NAME: 'People3',
  HOUSE_ID: 2 }
HOUSE_ID :  { name: 'House3',
  id: 3 }
People id { NAME: 'People1',
  HOUSE_ID: 1 }
People id { NAME: 'People2',
  HOUSE_ID: 2 }
People id { NAME: 'People3',
  HOUSE_ID: 2 }
```

Comment: You're not looping correctly. Be aware that your "i" in "houses" is "HOUSES", so you should loop slightly further, like that: https://jsfiddle.net/8zt69sjd/ . Alternatively, you can loop i in houses.HOUSES ;) Note: the fiddle is a possible answer already, hope this helps to find your own answer and understand the problem. I've added some further comments in the fiddle. Good try though, you deserve a +1 for trying to solve the problem and presenting the question correctly. Also, check nina's answer below for a rather brilliant solution instead of using loops.

Comment: Because `peoples.HOUSE_ID` doesn't exist

Comment: *"var houses and var peoples are the json files"* - Have you parsed the JSON? What does `console.log(houses[i]);` show? Please [edit] your question to make it clear exactly how the `houses` and `peoples` variables are set.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've edited my message with the results of console.log()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need no nested loop, just one for the key of people and the one for getting the names.

Method used:

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) get all own property names of the object
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) filter items and return only the wanted ones
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) return for every element a new value

```js
var data = { "HOUSES": { "1": { "NAME": "House1", "ID": 1 }, "2": { "NAME": "House2", "ID": 2 }, "3": { "NAME": "House3", "ID": 3 } }, "PEOPLE": { "1": { "NAME": "People1", "HOUSE_ID": 1 }, "2": { "NAME": "People2", "HOUSE_ID": 2 }, "3": { "NAME": "People3", "HOUSE_ID": 2 } } },
    result = Object.keys(data.PEOPLE).filter(function (k) {
        return data.PEOPLE[k].HOUSE_ID === 2;
    }).map(function (k) {
        return data.PEOPLE[k].NAME;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Edit:

Get all peoples and their houses.

```js
var data = { "HOUSES": { "1": { "NAME": "House1", "ID": 1 }, "2": { "NAME": "House2", "ID": 2 }, "3": { "NAME": "House3", "ID": 3 } }, "PEOPLE": { "1": { "NAME": "People1", "HOUSE_ID": 1 }, "2": { "NAME": "People2", "HOUSE_ID": 2 }, "3": { "NAME": "People3", "HOUSE_ID": 2 } } };

Object.keys(data.PEOPLE).forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(data.PEOPLE[k].NAME + ': ' + data.HOUSES[data.PEOPLE[k].HOUSE_ID].NAME);
});
```

Comment: Brilliant one. perhaps worth explaining how `Keys`, `filter` and `map` works in this specific case though.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. How can I do it dynamically? I mean : do someting when `PEOPLE.HOUSE_ID` === `HOUSES.ID`. Is it right to do this ?
`return data.PEOPLE[k].HOUSE_ID === data.HOUSES[k].ID;`

Comment: Ok thanks, because it always return false. Even if both IDs are equals

Comment: you need another variable as `k` for this part `=== data.HOUSES[k].ID`, because the property is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood task correctly here's solution:

```js
var houses = {
  "1": {
    "NAME": "House1",
    "ID": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "NAME": "House2",
    "ID": 2
  },
  "3": {
    "NAME": "House3",
    "ID": 3
  }
};
    
var peoples = {
  "1": {
    "NAME": "People1",
    "HOUSE_ID": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "NAME": "People2",
    "HOUSE_ID": 2
  },
  "3": {
    "NAME": "People3",
    "HOUSE_ID": 2
  }
};

for (var i in houses){
  console.log('List of people in ' + houses[i].NAME + ':');
  for(var j in peoples){
      if ( houses[i].ID === peoples[j].HOUSE_ID ){
        console.log(peoples[j].NAME);  
      } 
  }
}
```

Condition `houses[i].ID === peoples[j].HOUSE_ID` check is current people if they are living in house and than log their names in console.

Comment: Post the code here, not just as jsbin. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable. And include an explanation, not just code, so it will be informative to all the future readers.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for advice